# Quickly and Python Twisted

Tags: networking, python, quickly

I am creating a Quickly application that makes use of [Python Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com). When the user launches a window, I want to start the Twisted server I wrote. However, when I do this, it freezes the GUI, because the **reactor.run** method is constantly running after it is started. I need a way to start the Twisted reactor in its own thread, so that the GUI will continue to operate while the reactor is running. I have read about using Twisted with pyGTK in the Twisted documentation, but I am not sure how I would accomplish this with a Quickly application. What is the best way to start my Twisted server when a window opens without freezing the GUI?

**Update**:

My `if __name__ == '__main__'` statement at the end of my dialog file is:

```
print 'Preparing GLib'
GLib.idle_add(before_running)
print 'Staring Reactor'
from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.run()`
```

I have imported and installed **twisted.gtk3reactor** earlier on in the file. The **before_running** method contains `dialog = ClientDialog()` and `dialog.show`, as well as the rest of the code I want to run when the dialog opens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `python-gi` bindings on 12.04 or newer, you need to import and install the `twisted.internet.gireactor` or `twisted.internet.gtk3reactor`, before doing the reactor.run(). You also need to use this as your main loop, rather than running Gtk.main() or a GLib.MainLoop().run() yourself. If you are on an older version and using the old PyGTK+ bindings, then you need to use either `glib2reactor` or `gtk2reactor`.

Something like this:

```
from twisted.internet import gtk3reactor
from gi.repository import GLib
gtk3reactor.install()

GLib.idle_add(create_windows_and_do_stuff_method)
from twisted.internet import reactor

reactor.run()
```

The sequence is important, as importing the default reactor will result in it being installed, rather than the appropriate reactor, if a reactor is not already installed. Thus you need to install the proper one first, then do the `reactor.run()`. And instead of `Gtk.main_quit()`, you should `from twisted.internet import reactor` and use `reactor.stop()`.

Comment: I followed your instructions, but they did not work. I created an instance of twisted.internet.gireactor.GIReactor class, and ran its **run** method instead of running Gtk.main() in the **if __name__ == '__main__':** statement at the bottom of the code for my dialog, but it did not work. I put a **print** statement right before the listenTCP and run method calls, but the print statement never ran. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't create your own instance of the class in that way. I've updated the answer with a code example, to help you understand better.

Comment: Where I should I the **reactor.listenTCP** function call? In your example, only **reactor.run()** is called.

Comment: In the "create_windows_and_do_stuff_method" or somewhere else that is called from in there.

Comment: I updated my question to show the changes I have made. The `print 'Preparing GLib'` statement is never run.

Comment: I don't know what all your code is exactly, but this works fine here: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1063516/

Comment: I looked at the example on Ubuntu Pastebin. What I am trying to do is start the Twisted server when a dialog opens, not when the initial window opens. As I note in my question, the dialog is opened by **dialog = ClientDialog()** and **dialog.run()**. I am not sure where I should place **GLib.idle_add**

Comment: You should probably not use dialog.run, but use dialog.show instead, and handle which button is pressed in a callback for the response signal. If you want to do listenTCP, when the dialog is initialized, you should do it in the ClientDialog's __init__ probably. And ensure you aren't going to do it N times if the dialog is opened N times.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, I am still unsure as to where I should place **GLib.idle_add**, and what function I should have it call.